# Azure CDN - Whitelist only edge nodes IPs

Tags: azure, azure-cdn

We are distributing our content through Azure CDN. We have a RP server with public IP to which I can point Azure CDN endpoint. That all works fine.

However, I would want to automatically and regularly update firewall of the RP server to allow only Azure CDN Edge servers in (plus 1 or 2 extra IPs).

I found out that there is a list of these edge nodes available:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/rest/api/cdn/edgenodes/list

But I can't find simple way how to use this list to update firewall rules. Is there a tool / script / extension / setting which can help with this?

Any help really appreciated.

Comment: Where is your rp server hosted?

Comment: Hi @Alex, Azure, why?

Comment: There might be some sdk that you can use to accomplish your goal in conjunction with the HTTP endpoint

Comment: One more thing, is your server running Windows or Linux?

Comment: Windows. But I would ideally update the rules directly in Azure (VM Firewall)